# Where we can place the Page_Init in Razor

Tags: razor

I have a Page_Init code for setting no cache in C# code.I need to change the code to razor.
In razor how can we initialise the Page_Init .

here is my c# codebehind

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
 I want to implement the above code in razor
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The `Page_Init` (and other `Page_*` methods) are part of WebForms which was the original way ASP.NET worked. With ASP.NET MVC this logic should be in your controller, not your Razor view file.

Comment: Hi Dai can we set cache by using razor?

Comment: @Arun not in your Razor file, but in your Controller class.